# ROS melodic launching on a remote machine with robot upstart

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!
So I have a setup where I want to launch my ROS nodes via a launch file, which in turn will ssh into a udoo board and the launch the necessary files for hardware communication. The launch file works great normally when I do roslaunch, and I have set up a passwordless connection between the PC running ROS and udoo, using the ssh-rsa protocol.
I wanted to launch this on the robot upstart so used the robot-upstart package to create a service for launching. This is where my errors start, as the service does not be able to establish a ssh connection between the PC running ROS and the udoo board.
The error is as follows:

```
 Jan 09 15:12:26 seven-robot-2 systemd[1]: Started "bringup test_ru_launch".
    Jan 09 15:12:26 seven-robot-2 root[3298]: test_ru_launch: Using workspace setup file /home/seven-robot-2/Seven_ROS/devel/setup.bash
    Jan 09 15:12:26 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: <14>Jan  9 15:12:26 root: test_ru_launch: Using workspace setup file /home/seven-robot-2/Seven_ROS/devel/setup.bash
    Jan 09 15:12:27 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: <14>Jan  9 15:12:27 root: test_ru_launch: Launching ROS_HOSTNAME=seven-robot-2, ROS_IP=, ROS_MASTER_URI=http://sevenrobot2:11311/, ROS_HOME=/root/.ros, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
Jan 09 15:12:27 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: ls: cannot access '/etc/ros/melodic/test_ru_launch.d/*.xacro': No such file or directory
    Jan 09 15:12:27 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: <14>Jan  9 15:12:27 root: test_ru_launch: Generated launchfile: /tmp/test_ru_launch.launch
    Jan 09 15:12:27 seven-robot-2 root[3359]: test_ru_launch: Started roslaunch as background process, PID 3358, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
    Jan 09 15:12:27 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: <14>Jan  9 15:12:27 root: test_ru_launch: Started roslaunch as background process, PID 3358, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
    Jan 09 15:12:28 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: remote[192.168.2.23-0]: failed to launch on udooqdl:
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: Unable to establish ssh connection to [root@192.168.2.23:22]: Server u'192.168.2.23' not found in known_hosts
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: 
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: RLException: unable to start remote roslaunch child: 192.168.2.23-0
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: ... logging to /tmp/edd14b60-9001-11ed-8c81-7c8334b0242e/roslaunch-seven-robot-2-3358.log
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: [31B blob data]
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: started roslaunch server http://seven-robot-2:46315/
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: remote[192.168.2.23-0] starting roslaunch
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: remote[192.168.2.23-0]: creating ssh connection to 192.168.2.23:22, user[root]
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 test_ru_launch-start[3297]: [192.168.2.23-0] killing on exit
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 systemd[1]: test_ru_launch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 systemd[1]: test_ru_launch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Jan 09 15:12:29 seven-robot-2 systemd[1]: test_ru_launch.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

The service and launch file is as follows:

Service file:

```
# THIS IS A GENERATED FILE, NOT RECOMMENDED TO EDIT.

[Unit]
Description="bringup test_ru_launch"
After=network.target
Wants=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
After=multi-user.target
Wants=multi-user.target


[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/test_ru_launch-start
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

roslaunch file (part where ssh is established):

```
<group>
        <machine name="udooqdl" address="IP of the udoo" user="root" env-loader="/home/root/Seven_ROS/env_loader_udooqdl.sh" default="true"/>
      <rosparam file="$(find seven_robot_base)/params/robotParams.yaml" command="load" ns="$(arg uavcanNs)/uavcan_ros_bridge"/>
      <rosparam file="$(find seven_robot_localization)/params/diff_drive.yaml" command="load" ns="$(arg uavcanNs)/uavcan_ros_bridge"/>
      <include file="$(find uavcan_ros_bridge)/launch/uavcan_ros_bridge.launch">
        <arg name="uavcanNs" value="$(arg uavcanNs)"/>
        <arg name="laser_enabled" default="$(arg enable_Laser)"/>
        <arg name="publishuavcanTf" default="$(arg publishcanTf)"/>
        <arg name="enableMotors" default="$(arg motors_enabled)"/>
      </include>
    </group>
```

Not sure what is causing the error, any help/suggestions is appreciated. Happy to provide more information if needed. I am running ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. IP of the udoo is replaced by the actual IP address in the code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411174/ros-melodic-launching-on-a-remote-machine-with-robot-upstart/) by [Pran-Seven](https://answers.ros.org/users/114194/pran-seven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2023-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the issue turned out to be the fact that, this particular service launched as root, but we had established ssh with the remote machine as a user. Creating new keys and establishing it as the root seemed to fix the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Pran-Seven](https://answers.ros.org/users/114194/pran-seven/) with karma: 11 on 2023-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0